# Am I doing something wrong? Trying to load seperate stylesheet for firefox with modernizr

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

How exactly do I load a seperate stylesheet with modernizr?

This is what I wrote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.firefox,
    yep: 'assets/css/firefox.css'
});
</script>
```

I downloaded the entire modernizr package. I didnt dare to download a customized build because im not sure what exactly I need. However, Im pretty sure I did everything right. I served the code in the head of my document and targeted my css and declared that modernizr should test if the visitor uses a user agent named firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr is used for feature detected, not browser detection.